# Reducing Multiplications in a Set of Equations

Tags: optimization, algorithms

I have two equations:

`x = ab + bc + ad - cc`

`y = ab + cc + cd`

In these two equations combined, there is a cost of seven multiplications. I want to reduce this number down to three. I can do this, for example, by setting a temporary variable, called `temp1` and set it to the value `cc`. Now, my set of equations will look like this:

`x = ab + bc + ad - temp1`

and

`y = ab + temp1 + cd`

This updated set of equations now has a cost of six multiplications.

I have started by setting `temp1` to `ab` and using the distributive law with `bc` and `cc`, which can reduce the cost down to four multiplications, but I get stuck here:

`x = ad + c(b - c) + temp1`

`y = temp1 + c(c + d)`

What other factors, temporary variables, or additions/subtractions can I take from these two sets of equations to reduce the cost down to three?

Comment: Do you have a particular reason to believe that three multiplications ought to be possible?

Comment: The question posed asks for a solution with three multiplications, so my assumption is that it is possible.

Comment: Um, you're the one who asked this question...

Comment: I understand that. I am trying to answer the question that was posed to me (which stated that three multiplications is possible) - so I am relaying what the question asked me to the question I posted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I need to find a common factor between *x* and *y* to serve as the temporary variable. *ab* and *cc* are common, but *cd* is not. So, I will add and subtract *cd* to *x*:

`x = ab + bc + ad - cc + cd - cd`

`x = ab + ad + c(b+d) - c(c+d)`

`x = a(b+d) + c(b+d) - c(c+d)`

`x = (b+d)(a+c) - c(c+d)`

Now, we can assign a temporary variable: `tmp1 = c(c + d)` and use it in both x and y.

`x = (b+d)(a+c) - tmp1`

`y= ab + tmp1`

which only uses three multiplications.